# Find matrix row elements in a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a function which given a binary search tree `T` of integers and a rectangular matrix `M` of integers, verify if there exists a row of `M` whose values belong to `T`.
This is my code:

```
M = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
    ]

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.root = root
        self.left = left
        self.rigth = right

def FindRowInTree(T, M):
    if T is None:
        return False
    else:
        for r in M:
            for e in r:
                if e == T.root and FindRowInTree(T.left, M) is True and FindRowInTree(T.right, M) is True:
                    return True
                FindRowInTree(T.left, M) and FindRowInTree(T.right,M)
        return False

t = Tree(4, Tree(5, None, None), Tree(6, None, None))
x = FindRowInTree(t, M)
print(x)
```

It always returns `False`.

What would I need to change to make it work properly?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code, the definition of the tree object, and an output where it fails?

Comment: @j1-lee Yes, the tree has to be equivalent to at least one row of the matrix.

Comment: Are you talking about doing an *inorder traversal* of the tree to see if the elements match the row?  Is the tree guaranteed to be ordered?  Are the rows of the matrix guaranteed to be sorted?  Does the tree need to have the same ordering as the row in the matrix or does order not matter at all?  (I'm asking about ordering because you tagged this with "binary search" which is based entirely around ordering, but you didn't explain any of this in the question.)

Comment: @Samwise I have to verify if the elements of a row of the matrix are a subset of the nodes of the tree. The order of the nodes is not to be considered.

Comment: But the tree isn't guaranteed to be ordered, correct?  That means you can't do a binary search; you need to traverse the entire tree to find any given value.

Comment: @Samwise Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the problem into pieces.  First write a function to find a single value in the tree:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.root = root
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return (
            self.root == value
            or self.left is not None and value in self.left
            or self.right is not None and value in self.right
        )
```

Note that with an *ordered* binary tree, you could make this function more efficient by having it only check left or right depending on how the value you're looking for compares to the root value; that's what a "binary search" is.  Since your tree is unordered, though, you just need to search both children at each node, meaning you're traversing the entire tree.

In any case, once you have a function that looks up a single value, all you need to do is call it in a loop:

```
def find_row_in_tree(tree, matrix):
    return any(
        all(i in tree for i in row)
        for row in matrix
    )
```

If you're trying to do this in a more efficient way, an unordered binary tree is not doing you any favors; I'd just write a utility function to convert it to something more useful, like a `set`:

```
def tree_to_set(tree):
    if tree is None:
        return set()
    return {tree.root} | tree_to_set(tree.left) | tree_to_set(tree.right)

def find_row_in_tree(tree, matrix):
    tree_as_set = tree_to_set(tree)
    return any(tree_as_set.issuperset(row) for row in matrix)
```